# What's the most widely used pronunciation of the Unix /etc directory?

Tags: unix, etc

What is the correct pronunciation of the directory `/etc`? Or, if there isn't a definitively "correct" way to say it, what is the most widely used pronunciation?

I usually say the letter names spelled out: "ee-tee-see", but am acutely aware that a lot of other folks call it "et-see" (to rhyme with Betsy).

Comment: Do they know what "etc" stands for? I always feel like I'm illiterate when spelling it out. Probably leftover from an old school trauma.

Comment: Unless one of us has talked to everyone else on the planet it's kind of unlikely that any of use could possibly know what the most common pronunciation is. Besides, what difference does it make?

Comment: @John: You only need to talk to a statistically significant number of knowledgeable people to know what's common. A large enough sample size should get a reasonably small statistical error, no? It doesn't really make any difference. It's just a matter of fun trivia.

Comment: @John: sometimes it's a pet peeve. I cringe when people call patch cables cords. Maybe it's my Aspergers, but it still annoys me. Other people hate it if you replace the toilet paper roll the wrong way...*shrug*

Comment: +1 reopen vote.  This is an interesting question, do we need to be so strict about the rules?

Comment: @Doug, yes we do need to be pretty strict about the rules. Already this question has resulted in the very kind of argumentative comments that we're trying to avoid. The question itself should, at the very least, have been community wiki.

Comment: @John: Again, other than comments arguing about whether or not this should be closed, what comments are you referring to? Also, I'd have happily made it community wiki on request.

Answer (score 6):

Slash ee tee cee but there's no real "correct" way. I remember the first time I spoke to an American about "cash" on a content router, got very confused and then realized he meant "cache"

it's just cultural!

Comment: Please be more specific regarding "cash" vs. "cache" because they're pronounced the same as far as I know.

Comment: Some people pronounce "cache" similar to "catch".  Regarding the question itself, I always just spell it out.  I visibly wince when someone pronounces it "etsy" (like Betsy).

Comment: I say it out as etcetera, but often find myself in practice saying slash ee tee cee, mainly because I think I end up explaining to others three times what I mean because they can't figure out etcetera IS etc. It's like dealing with educated people who can't figure out the difference between LOSE and LOOSE. @#%!!

Comment: @Farseeker: You must be from Australia :) [from what I can tell it's pronounced "cash" *everywhere* but Australia (and maybe NZ) -- even in France they say "cash", apparently]

Comment: @Dan, this is the very kind of comment that results from such subjective questions, which is why I voted to close it.

Comment: @John: The only arguing going on in this entire thread is whether or not this question should be closed. The answers and comments have otherwise been nothing but good discussion. I'm puzzled by your assessment.

Comment: It's good to see post-modernism is alive and well.  "It's cultural." :P

Comment: This is no attempt to answer the question.  A sample size of 1 is very small.

Answer (score 4):

I've never heard anyone pronouncing it other than 'eee-tee-see'.

Comment: That's what I always say, but then I'm Russian... Ah, and you seem to be from not too far away? Must be some Slavic dialect :)

Comment: yup, croatian ;) But, i work with 10 different nationalities ranging from Newzealanders to Swedes, and none of them pronounces it differently.

Answer (score 3):

I call it "et cetera" myself.

Comment: +1. I use the full pronunciation as well.

Answer (score 3):

Does no one else just call it "etts", as in the sound of the first syllable of "etcetera"?

Comment: +1, I do.  Every now and then I throw out "ett-cee" if another person isn't picking up on my [mis-]pronunciation.

Answer (score 3):

I've always said "etsee" even though "et cetera" is what I say for the Latin phrase.

Answer (score -2):

Most people here are wrong.  Go to the proper source and listen to the sound clip:

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/et%20cetera

Comment: I was once told that the 'etc' directory didn't stand for 'et cetra' but rather 'Every Thing's Config'.  O_o

Comment: That sounds like a folk backronym, and I hate those.

Comment: Merriam nor Webster knew anything about /etc.

Comment: Just because it's created on a UNIX filesystem, @reinierpost, does not grant it unique grammatical properties.

Comment: It does, but pronunciation is not a grammatical property.