# What do these abbreviations stand for?

Tags: linux, unix, directory

Some directories are easy to understand the meaning

/`usr`
/`bin`
...

But for the next ones, I have no idea.

/`etc`
/`opt`

`opt` for optional?
`etc` for electronic t...... configuration (no idea for t)

I would like to know what these abbreviations mean.

Comment: Pedantry, I know, but FYI /etc, /opt, /bin and the rest are *not* acronyms: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym

Comment: @Zayne You're right. I edited the question. But I was sure that `etc` was an acronym.

Comment: Similar post on AU: http://askubuntu.com/q/138547/62483

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Strangely enough `/usr` actually means Unix System Resources.

"The "etc" in "/etc/bin" really does stand for "etcetera." In early Unix systems, the most important directory was the "bin" directory (short for "binaries" -- compiled programs), and "etc" was for trivial stuff like startup, shutdown and admin. The list of things you need for running Linux is: a program binary, etcetera, etcetera -- in other words, a sole vital item, plus some less important bits and pieces.

Today, "etc" holds system-wide configuration files that you'd almost never do without -- hardly unimportant." --http://searchenterpriselinux.techtarget.com/tip/0,289483,sid39_gci1098161,00.html

Comment: I thought that `/usr` means users. But your explanation removes the strange feelings I had about my "translation". Thanks!

Comment: Also, here's a good breakdown of the directory structure on FreeBSD: http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/dirstructure.html

Comment: /usr originally meant “user”. “Unix System Resources” is a backronym and it doesn’t make much sense either, because the system resources are in /bin and /sbin; /usr can be mounted much later from within a running unix system. Canonical source: http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/bellLabs/unix/PreliminaryUnixImplementationDocument_Jun72.pdf (p.13-14 in the PDF) from Bell Labs in ’72.

Comment: @moeffju - thanks the the 'bitsaver' I remember single-stepping though UNIX v7 code to learn the meaning of interrupts. And, yes - my first home directory was /usr/michael - and /usr/local was "born" to allow users to add stuff in a "local" root. My guess that /usr became "UNIX Software Repository" is because /usr/src is where you (re-)built UNIX whenever you added a device (or fixed a bug). My other favorite file was /usr/sys/conf.h - as that is the file I remember as being the conf file of conf files (e.g., where disk partitions were defined). Ah - the memories :) Great start of a new year!

Comment: @iainlbc I don't think so, I think its "User System Resources" if not just short for "user"... https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/usr.html

Answer (score 29):

You might find the output from "man hier" fascinating

Comment: Nice. It's funny because `hier` means yesterday in french. Hierarchy wasn<t my first thought :-)

Comment: @Luc_M and in German "hier" means "here." :-)

Comment: The output doesn't answer the question (what do abbreviations like etc and opt stand for), but interesting nonetheless.

Comment: If you don't have a linux system on hand just google *man hier*

Answer (score 7):

for the curious reader, `sbin` is short for “system binaries” (although it’s sometimes been described as being short for “static binaries”, because on some systems the executables in `/sbin` would always be statically-linked to ensure a bootable system if `/lib` was destroyed); `lib`, fairly obviously, stands for “libraries”.

`/var` contains “variable files” — things like logs, process IDs, temporary directories, mail spools.

`/proc` (on systems which have a `proc` filesystem) originally just contained information about running processes, but Linux extended this to include lots of other information, too (for example, `cat /proc/cpuinfo`).

On some older Unix variants, `/etc` often contained executable programs (and actually may still do, in some cases), rather than simply being restricted to configuration files. If memory serves, `ifconfig` was actually `/etc/ifconfig` on SVR4 systems some years ago.

If you use a Solaris machine, you’ll also see `xpg4` (standing for “X/Open Portability Guide”), `ccs` (“C Compiler System”), and `ucb` (“University of California, Berkeley” — BSD compatibity).

You may find reading up on the [FHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) helpful :)

Answer (score 6):

`/etc` stands for et cetera.  Wikipedia references [a Bell Labs document from '72](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard#cite_note-8) that calls it etcetera.

Comment: +1 That likely would have answered this [now closed] question. http://serverfault.com/questions/137328/whats-the-most-widely-used-pronunciation-of-the-unix-etc-directory/137397

Answer (score 1):

The Filesystem Hierarchy Standard has information on etc history:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

> There has been controversy over the meaning of the name itself. In
>   early versions of the UNIX Implementation Document from Bell labs,
>   /etc is referred to as the etcetera directory,[24] as this directory
>   historically held everything that did not belong elsewhere (however,
>   the FHS restricts /etc to static configuration files and may not
>   contain binaries). Since the publication of early documentation,
>   the directory name has been re-designated in various ways. Recent
>   interpretations include backronyms such as "Editable Text
>   Configuration" or "Extended Tool Chest".